# Receiving incomplete data when using HttpWebResponse::GetResponseStream method

Tags: c#, .net

Is HttpWebResponse::GetResponseStream() guaranteed to get all data contained in an HTTP response?  Or do I need to create some kind of loop and wait to make sure all data is being sent from the server to which I'm connected?  The code below successfully grabs a response about 50% of the time.

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://JohnDoeServerSite.com");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = @"text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    req.Host = "http://JohnDoeServerSite.com";
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.1)";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        sw.Write(xml);
    }
    string result;
    using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    using (Stream st = res.GetResponseStream())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);  //  Added to see if additional data would be sent (perhaps?)
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            st.Flush();   
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In theory it should return everything. Perhaps if there is something odd about the web server's response that could throw it off, but that's unlikely. In your code I would remove the Thread.Sleep and the st.Flush(), since those are unnecessary and even bad (in the case of Thread.Sleep)

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(..)` is not necessary, the stream will acknowledge the appropriate `EOF` (end-of-file) marker based on the transmission. If there's more data to read across the network, the stream read will simply block. When you say "successfully grabs a response", what do you mean? Is the stream just empty? You should check `res.StatusCode`, maybe the server is responding with a 404, 500, or some other error?

Comment: `GetResponseStream` doesn't return any data. It returns a `Stream`. The `Stream` can be read to get all of the data. There's no hidden data, nor any need to "coax" data from the `Stream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this more, it turns out that the server was not sending all of the data in its entirety. It seems that Michael Yoon is right in saying that everything should be returned.